# Inhomogeneous Linear Recurrence relation for Merge Sort confusion on

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

Question: $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n$   ==> Note our result will be $\Theta$(nlog(n))

The very first step you should take is putting everything in the form $T(n)=b^np^n$ so
$T(n) - 2T(n/2) = n$

Because this is an inhomogenous relation, we want to turn it into a solvable homogenous problem.

---

Note we can treat n as 2^k becasue of the bn property.

So now we have $T(2^k) - 2T({2^k}/2) = 2^k$

---

Next, we multiple both sides by 2 to get the k+1 condition,
so $2T(2^k)-4T(2^{k-1}) = 2^{k+1}$

---

Then we can have a duplicate of the above term, except write it in terms of k+1 so  $T(2^{k+1})-2(T^k)= 2^{k+1} $

And then subtract the two terms 
$T(2^{k+1})-2(T^k)= 2^{k+1}  -  2T(2^k)-4T(2^{k-1}) = 2^{k+1}$

to get: $T(2^{k+1})-4T(2^k)-4T(2^{k-1}) = 0$

---

Next we can rewrite $T(2^k)$ as $X^p$

so,

$X^{p+1} -4X^P -4X^{p-1} = 0$

...

So on $(X^{p-1})(X^2-4X-4)= 0$  //Ignore the first part//

so, $X^2-4X-4=0$ and our roots become x=2,2

---

Because the roots are not distinct, we use
the formula,
$\sum c_ir^{p}p^{i-1}$

---

which brings us to $(2)^p + 2^{p}*(p)$

which $p = 2^k$
and $2^k = n$

and so $2^{2^k}+2^{2^k}(2^k)$
which should be $2^{n}+2^{n}*n$ ...

But my professor treats 
$\sum c_ir^{p}p^{i-1}$ the 
$p^{i-1}$ as a separate value of just K not $2^k$ in which then K = log(n) ... why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Considering for $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$

$$
T(2^{\log_2 n}) = 2T(2^{\log_2(\frac n2)})+n
$$

calling now $T'(u) = T(2^u)$ we have

$$
T'(\log_2 n) = 2T'(\log_2 n - 1) + n
$$

and calling now $u = \log_2 n$ we have

$$
T'(u) = 2T'(u-1)+2^u
$$

which is a linear recurrence with solution given by

$$
T'(u) = T'_h(u) + T'_p(u)\\
T'_h(u) = 2T'_h(u-1)\\
T'_p(u) = 2T'_p(u-1)+2^u
$$

so we have

$$
T'_h(u) = C 2^{u-1}
$$

now making $T'_p(u) = C(u) 2^{u-1}$ and substituting into the particular recurrence we obtain the new recurrence

$$
C(u)-C(u-1) = 2\Rightarrow C(u) = 2u
$$

so

$$
T'(u) = \left(C+2u \right) 2^{u-1}
$$

hence

$$
T(n) = C_1n+n\log_2 n
$$